# How to compare two object of model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have object of search-model in cache (i saved him from get-query) and i get with get-request other object same model.

I want to compare these objects, but if i don't change parametrs, anyway i have "false" result in this code:

```
public class SearchO
{
  public  List<SellsLive> Data;
  public SellsLiveSearch Query;
}


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Result(SellsLiveSearch ObjectModelFromQuery, string Ser)
    {           
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[Ser] != null)
                        {SearchO ObjectModelFromCache = (SearchO)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[Ser];
                         if(ObjectModelFromCache.Query==ObjectModelFromQuery)
 ...
    }
```

Why this can happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It return false because you are comparing reference types and the objects are not the same reference (even through all the property values may be the same).

`ObjectModelFromQuery` is a new instance of `SellsLiveSearch` initialized in your action method. `ObjectModelFromCache.Query` is another instance of `SellsLiveSearch` retrieved from session.

If `SellsLiveSearch` contains a (say) `ID` property which uniquely identifies the object, then you could use  `if(ObjectModelFromCache.Query.ID == ObjectModelFromQuery.ID)`. Otherwise you need to override the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods, and the `==` and `!=` operators of `SellsLiveSearch`. Refer [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28VS.80%29.aspx) for a detailed example.

Side note: In general, you should not be passing a complex object to a GET method. Apart from the ugly query string this creates, you could easily exceed the query string character limit and throw an exception. In addition, if type of `SellsLiveSearch` contains properties which are complex objects or collections, binding will fail and those properties will be `null`. Instead pass an ID value identifying the the object.

```
public ActionResult Result(int ID, string Ser)
{
  ...
  if(ObjectModelFromCache.Query.ID == ID)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to compare two object

```
    MyClass object1 = new MyClass("test");
    MyClass object2 = new MyClass("test"); 

    object1.equals(object2);
```

Comment: I tried

'ObjectModelFromCache.Query.equals(ObjectModelFromQuery)'
 
result "false".

This is right or no? What is ("test")?

Comment: false means both objects are not same.

Answer (score 0):

Override the equals Method in your class

Answer (score 0):

using equals method is the right approach. Though you should override the Equal method in your class and match the Unique value for equivalence.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public overrides bool Equals(object obj)
    {
           if(obj==null)
               return false;
           return (MyObject)obj).Id.Equals(this.Id)
    }
}
```

I hope this make sense.